# Translation of "取り扱いを決めて物事の決まりをつけること。"

Tags: translation

I searched for the meaning of 処分{しょぶん} in `dictionary.goo.ne.jp` and I come up with this:

> 取り扱いを決めて物事の決まりをつけること。...

to me, it seem like "handling things" but I can't put above sentence into plain English.

remark, these are what I believe to be meaning of words in above sentence from Jim Breen's WWWJDIC

> 取り扱い :(n) treatment; service; handling; management;
>
> 決める : (v1,vt) (1) to decide; to choose; to determine; to make up one's mind; to resolve; to    set one's heart on; to settle; to arrange; to set; to appoint; to fix;
>
> つける (v1,vt) to turn on; to switch on; to light up; KD

Comment: What, "物事の決まりをつけること" doesn't sound natural to my ears :-)  処分 is a general word which can mean several things, so please show the context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I translated 取り扱いを決めて物事の決まりをつけること as "to decide the treatment for the thing and to determine the way for the thing" but this sentence is circumlocutory. And つける in 決まりをつける doesn't mean "to switch on" but "get determined".

When 処分 is used for persons, it means punishment like 彼は規則を破ったために処分を受けた(He received punishment for breaking a rule).

When 処分 is used for  material goods, it means "to get rid" like "discard" and "sell out".